# Using data from a website, match it to a table and pull data

Tags: python, html, mysql

After hours and hours of looking around and reading documents, I have to call for help and sanity. I'm no python expert or even HTML expert, so I'd appreciate every small bit of help that I can get.

I can pay for a little time if needed...

What I'm trying to do is:

Two webpages. One is in my server and one isn't. The one that isn't in my server (order.asp), has this line:

```
<FONT CLASS="fv">Estimated Weight of Order:</FONT></TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT"><FONT CLASS="fv">XX.XXoz&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;XX.XXg</FONT>
```

I need something that I can put in my server, queries the weight from the page that isn't on my server (order.asp page) and matches the weight with a shipping price that I would have on my page (as a table or maybe with ifs).

There will be different order pages (order1.asp order2.asp order3.asp) with different weights. The script or whatever should do that for ea. wpage.

Here's a flowchart I just made to help understand:

http://www.gliffy.com/go/publish/image/5123674/L.png

A very helpful user already gave me this piece of code:

html = open("html.txt").read()
out = open("foundWeights.txt", "w")

```
#split html on order number
legoOrders = html.split("Order #")

for order in legoOrders[1:]:
  print order
  orderNumber = order.split("<")[0]

  weightString = order.split('Estimated Weight of Order:</FONT></TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT"><FONT CLASS="fv">')[1]
  splitWeightString = weightString.split('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;')
  splitStringFinal = splitWeightString[1].split("<")

  grams = splitStringFinal[0]
  ozs = weightString.split('&nbsp')[0]

  out.write(str(orderNumber) + "\t" + str(grams) + "\t" + str(ozs) + "\n"
```

Which pulls out the order number, and weight in ozs and grams.

What I don't know how to do is, having a table of shipping prices and weight ranges, match that weight to a shipping price, pull the shipping price and... well, do some things with it.

Ideally, if I knew how to do that (I don't know nothing in python, but I do know programming basics and C), I could pull the order total too, sum the order total and the shipping price, and **FINALLY** get a grand total.

I hope I made it clear.

All the best,
Gerald

---

This is how the page order.asp will look like (varying the weight and order total numbers):

http://pastebin.com/uH18CF5k

---

Getting there slowly. I added this to your code @duhaime

```
 #get Shipping Range
    test = "B"
    if ( 0 < grams < 100 ):
        test = "A"
    if ( 100 < grams < 500):
        test = "A"
```

Along with the str(test) in the out.write.

However, it prints a B when I run it, but it should print an A. Know what's wrong?

Comment: Howdy @Brick Top! Do you have a chart that matches shipping prices to weights? Or, do you have a formula that you can use to calculate a shipping price given a weight value? If you have this, I can edit the code above...

Comment: Heya @duhaime and thanks for your help before! I do have a chart for weights and shipping prices. However, for the sake of the example, you could use 1 as shipping price for 0-100 grams, 2 for 100-500 grams and 3 for 500-2000. It really doesn't matter to me, as long as the basics are there. That's my biggest problems, I don't have much of a basic, but I do well in learning visually. I. E. if you paste a code that does that and assigns a variable (shipping price) that changes to 1-2-3 depending on whether the shipping weight is 0-2000 grams, I can understand it and integrate it in real life.

Comment: The trouble with the above is that grams is a string, not a mathematical value, so Python tries to compare the string "61.44g" with the integers you provide but can't do so, so it doesn't change the value of test. I'll post a code snippet in a second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks again for your feedback, @Brick Top. This code pulls down the Order Number, Grand Total, Order Total, Shipping Cost, Weight in Grams, and Weight in Ozs from the html, and writes them to a tab-separated text file that you can open and easily review in Excel.

EDIT: The script also calculates the shipping class, based on the weight of the order in grams. The Shipping Class is indicated in the final column of the out file:

```
from decimal import *

html = open("html.txt").read()
out = open("legoShipping.txt", "w")

out.write("Order Number" + "\t" +
          "Grand Total (currency)" + "\t" +
          "Order Total (currency)" + "\t" +
          "Shipping Cost (currency)" + "\t" +
          "Order Weight (grams)" + "\t" +
          "Order Weight (oz.)" + "\t" +
          "Shipping Class" + "\n")

#split html on order number
legoOrders = html.split("Order #")

for order in legoOrders[1:]:
  orderNumber = order.split("<")[0]

  #get Grand Total
  grand = order.split("<TD>Grand&nbsp;Total:</TD>")[1].split('<TD ALIGN="RIGHT"><B>')[1].split("<")[0].split('&nbsp;')
  grandCurrency = grand[0]
  grandTotal = grand[1]

  #get Order Total
  orderTotalAndCurrency = order.split('<TD>Order Total:</TD>')[1].split('<TD ALIGN="RIGHT">')[1].split("<")[0].split('&nbsp;')
  orderCurrency = orderTotalAndCurrency[0]
  orderTotal = orderTotalAndCurrency[1]

  #get Shipping Cost
  shipping = order.split("<TD>Shipping:</TD>")[1].split('<TD ALIGN="RIGHT">')[1].split("<")[0].split('&nbsp;')
  shippingCurrency = shipping[0]
  shippingCost = shipping[1]

  #get Weights
  weightString = order.split('Estimated Weight of Order:</FONT></TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT"><FONT CLASS="fv">')[1]
  splitWeightString = weightString.split('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;')
  splitStringFinal = splitWeightString[1].split("<")
  grams = splitStringFinal[0]
  ozs = weightString.split('&nbsp')[0]

  #convert grams to mathematical value
  gramsValue = Decimal(grams[:-1])

  #create default shipping class value. Set it to ""
  shippingClass = ""

  if gramsValue > 0:
    if gramsValue < 100:
      shippingClass = "A"

  if gramsValue >= 100:
    if gramsValue < 200:
      shippingClass = "B"

  out.write(str(orderNumber) + "\t" +
            str(grandTotal) + " (" + str(grandCurrency) + ")" + "\t" +
            str(orderTotal) + " (" + str(orderCurrency) + ")" + "\t" +
            str(shippingCost) + " (" + str(shippingCurrency) + ")" + "\t" +
            str(grams) + "\t" +
            str(ozs) + "\t" +
            str(shippingClass) + "\n")
```

Output in OpenOffice Calc:

[image]

Comment: Does this work, or do you want to compute a new shipping cost based on the package weight?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's helping me learn a little more than the basics fairly quick. In this case, the shipping price shouldn't have been posted, but it would have been for our little script to find out. Can you do something like if elses on python? If we were in C, what I would do very basicly: if ( weight > 0 && weight < 100 ) { shippingZone = A } ... and so on. Then, A, B or C would assign the prices according to my table/database/constants.

Comment: Oh @duhaime, I also edited and added a flowchart if it helps with the understanding.

Comment: How's this? You can make more shipping classes if you like, following the examples in the code. You could also calculate shipping classes based on the weight on ozs, if you would prefer. If any of this is unclear, just say the word and I'll be happy to explicate.

Comment: Wonderful! I'll look more into it tomorrow, and mess around with all that I know now. I'll post any question tomorrow. Cheers!